# When passing arguments with php shell script eval isn't properly executing the script

Tags: php, bash, shell, ffmpeg

This is the part of my php script:

```
$result ='ffmpeg -re -i /home/neotel/sample.mp4 -s 320x240 -vf setdar=4:3 -r 
25 -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f mpegts 
udp://192.168.88.211:5000' 
$FILE1 = escapeshellarg($result);
$output = shell_exec("sh testpetar.sh $FILE1 2>&1");
```

This is my shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILE1=$1
FILE2="nohup "
FILE3=" > log.txt"
FILE="$FILE2$FILE1$FILE3"
eval $FILE
```

I am trying to pass the $results strings as the $FILE1 argument and then concatenate it with the strings $FILE2 and $FILE3 to form a whole ffmpeg command and execute it as a script in shell. When i execute it manually through Putty it is working properly, but when i am passing the $results command from php the eval function is not working.

Comment: PHP is malformed, first line must end with semicolon.

Comment: Putting commands in variables and then executing them with `eval` is a recipe for disaster. Just execute the command directly. That may not solve the problem, but it'll eliminate one possible source of trouble.